# Any tips for writing cross-browser Greasemonkey userscripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a few scripts that clean-up some of the sites I use. But, I have now switched over to Chrome from Firefox and some of the scripts don't work, even though I can install them.

Can anyone offer any tips on how to write Userscripts that work (nearly) cross-browser? Specifically, Firefox and Chrome, and maybe Opera.

Comment: You may lift some useful functions from my [FallBack GM API](http://hwi.ath.cx/code/other/gm_scripts/fallbackgmapi/) script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working on [a User Script engine comparison table](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/wiki/Comparison-Table) which should help you know which GM_APIs you can depend on.

Other then that you need to write cross browser JavaScript which is a long topic; I would recommend [the DOM compatibility tables offered by QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) for cross browser DOM usage.

Comment: That table is nice, but it's out of date, Greasemonkey does support `@icon` and `@version`, for example, as of GM version 9.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just to install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo). It will allow you to run most GM scripts, as-is, on Chrome.

Comment: @Erik Vold:  Tampermonkey is a tip for both.   Why contort your code for a fleeting version of Chrome (each version seems to change (improve) it's support for GM), when you can just use existing Firefox scripts **NOW**.   Write the simple way (Firefox style) and use everywhere that matters.

Answer (score 1):

**Firefox:** as usual

**Chrome:** http://www.techrena.net/internet/enable-greasemonkey-user-scripts-google-chrome-easily/

**Opera:** http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/examples/#greasemonkey

Comment: That Chrome information is out of date as of Chrome version 4.